# how can i get the "row leaving scroll" event in ListView/ScrollView

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I have the following code:

```
<ScrollView>
    ...
    <ListView ... renderRow={ (rowData) => return (
        <SomeCustomComponent> {rowData} </SomeCustomComponent>
    )}/>
</ScrollView>
```

How can I determine when the user 'leaves' the current viewed row and scrolling its way to the next one?